# JS multiplier doesn't work

Tags: javascript

that's my code but it doesn't work it should multiply everything within the brackets and then multiply it with 20?

```js
var type = $1;
var number_items = $2;
var shipping = $3;

var result = (number_items * type * shipping) * 20;

return result;
```

Comment: $1 is not a valid number.

Comment: You should use `return` only inside functions

Comment: @SureshAtta — It's a valid variable name though. It's value might be a valid number. The OP failed to supply a [mcve] or a clear problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can multiply string and a number.

```
//python

str = 'text';
output = 2 * str;
now output looks like 'texttext';
```

But JavaScript has no way to multiply numbers and string. But you have done this by another way.

```
//javascript

let output = "";
let str = "text";
for (let i=0; i<3; i++){
    output += str;
}
now output looks like 'texttext'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your number variables are not valid integers because of the `$` character and you are also returning outside of a function. Remove the `$`s and wrap the code in a function.

```
function getCost() {
    var type = 1;
    var number_items = 2;
    var shipping = 3;

    var result = (number_items * type * shipping) * 20;

    return '$' + result;
}

getCost(); // returns '$120'
```